# TensorFlow works in command prompt but doesn't work in spyder( ipython)

Tags: python-3.7

My spyder version is 3.3.4 in anaconda( version 3.5), and my Ipython version is 7.4.0. Now my python version is 3.7.3 and I installed tensorflow of 1.13.1 version. When I open spyder and input the commands "import tensorflow as tf ",it is always running and I can not use function of tf. But I can use tensorflow in python through command prompt, I'm just not used to editing function in command prompt. So I want to know what is the reason that tensorflow doesn't work in spyder while running well in command prompt.